# Append text file data to log file, .bat

Tags: batch-file

This `.bat` file is used for website replication, transferring files from development to production and then produces a log file with job statistics. I'd like to include the contents of a text file at the end of the log file. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
@ECHO off
    IF "%1"=="" goto :Syntax
    for %%d in (%1) do call :sub0 %%d
    goto :END

    :sub0
    Echo Replicating Site %1
    rem subinacl /subdirectories D:\inetpub\%1\*.* /setowner=Administrators REM /grant=Administrators=f /grant=SYSTEM=f
    robocopy D:\inetpub\%1 \\111.111.11.11\D$\inetpub\%1 /MIR /ZB /NP /R:3 /W:3 /XD SiteReplication /XD SiteLogs /XD Administration /XD sitestatistics /XF calendar_secure.asp /XF navigation_editor.asp  /LOG:logs\test%USERNAME%.log
    robocopy D:\inetpub\%1 \\111.111.11.11\D$\inetpub\%1 /MIR /ZB /NP /R:3 /W:3 /XD SiteReplication /XD SiteLogs /XD Administration /XD sitestatistics /XF calendar_secure.asp /XF navigation_editor.asp  /LOG+:logs\test.log


    goto :EOF

    :Syntax
    ECHO Usage:  _REP_SITE WEB_Site
    ECHO.
    ECHO Where:  "WEB_Site"   is the name of the folder you want to replicate
    ECHO                      i.e. _REP_SITE www.test.com
    ECHO.
    goto :END

    :END
    exit
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like:

```
type textfile.txt >> test.log
```

?

(Note that in the batch file it *looks* like you're currently creating two separate log files. Is that deliberate?)

Alternatively, if you need to copy the files elsewhere you can just do:

```
copy test.log+textfile.txt destination.log
```

That creates `destination.log` from `test.log` with `textfile.log` appended on the end.

Comment: Run `echo "ASDF" >> test.log` for arbitrary text.